# How to cut the transparent part of an image with NodeJS and GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, transparency, graphicsmagick

I use the npm package gm to resize and crop images. How can I use this package to automatically cut the transparent part from top and bottom of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the [trim()](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-trim) function does more or less what I wanted.